# 2D Plot Riemann Zeta-function

Tags: programming

I want to plot the Riemann zeta-function as a 2 dimensional vector field. Where would be the fastest and easiest way to program this plot?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB.  In fact, it even has examples in its documentation for how to do it.  It would first give you the values, and then you would plot it using MATLAB's "quiver" function if you wanted a vector field.

Check the documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.zeta.html)